# R condition else if

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

in the output r says I have an error i.e that my condition has a length > 1 in my first if condition

```
x<-0:100
x
if(x<=39){
  "Your grade is E(POOR)"
}else if(x<=49){
  "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)"
}else if(x<=59){
  "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)"
}else if(x<=69){
  "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)"
}else{
  "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if anybody has mentioned it yet, but 'if' is typically used for a vector of length 1 and 'ifelse' is used for a vector of length >1. Your vector is long, so use 'ifelse' or other options in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives:

## base R

We can use a vector of named values and `findInterval` (or `cut`):

```r
x <- 0:100
grades <- c(
  "Your grade is E(POOR)" = 39,
  "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)" = 49,
  "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)" = 59,
  "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)" = 69,
  "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A" = 100)
names(grades)[findInterval(x, c(0, grades+1), rightmost.closed = TRUE)]
```

While minor, I chose to keep the scores at the numbers you chose, and then use `grades+1` inside the `findInterval`. You could just as easily done `"Your grade is E(POOR)" = 40`, suggesting a strict-inequality of `< 40`, and then used `c(0, grades)` for the same effect.

## dplyr::case_when

```r
dplyr::case_when(
  x <= 39 ~ "Your grade is E(POOR)",
  x <= 49 ~ "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)",
  x <= 59 ~ "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)",
  x <= 69 ~ "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)",
  TRUE    ~ "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A"
)
```

(Oops, I just saw that @GuedesBF already answered this ...)

## data.table::fcase

```r
data.table::fcase(
  x <= 39 , "Your grade is E(POOR)",
  x <= 49 , "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)",
  x <= 59 , "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)",
  x <= 69 , "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)",
  rep(TRUE, length(x)), "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A"
)
```

---

Benchmark:

```r
bench::mark(
 dplyr = dplyr::case_when( x <= 39 ~ "Your grade is E(POOR)", x <= 49 ~ "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)", x <= 59 ~ "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)", x <= 69 ~ "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)", TRUE    ~ "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A" ),
 data.table = data.table::fcase( x <= 39 , "Your grade is E(POOR)", x <= 49 , "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)", x <= 59 , "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)", x <= 69 , "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)", rep(TRUE, length(x)), "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A" ),
 baseR = names(grades)[findInterval(x, c(0, grades+1), rightmost.closed = TRUE)]
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result      memory time                gc                   
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>      <list> <list>              <list>               
# 1 dplyr      171.91µs 197.93µs     4952.        NA     8.81  2247     4    453.8ms <chr [101]> <NULL> <bench_tm [2,251]>  <tibble [2,251 × 3]> 
# 2 data.table   5.46µs   6.38µs   148889.        NA    14.9   9999     1     67.2ms <chr [101]> <NULL> <bench_tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 × 3]>
# 3 baseR        3.09µs   3.68µs   251231.        NA    25.1   9999     1     39.8ms <chr [101]> <NULL> <bench_tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 × 3]>
```

So the base-R method is the fastest (I'm looking mostly at the `` `itr/sec` `` value, higher is better).

Comment: I did not know `fcase`. Looks like a promising (and efficient) replacement for `dplyr::case_when`

Comment: `case_when` is to `fcase` as `if_else` is to `fifelse`, there are likely other similar-functions with internal optimizations. They are mostly in-step, though I do like that `case_when` allows `TRUE ~ 123` whereas `fcase` requires `rep(TRUE, .N), 123` since it does not allow recycling at all.

Comment: `TRUE ~ 123` is really nice, but i always felt like it is non-intuitive and kind of hacky.
The (not so) new option with `.default = 123` feels a lot more natural to me (although not included in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Here your `x` is a vector, rather than a single value for `if` condition

A workaround is iterating through each value from `1:100`, e.g.,

```
Xval <- 0:100
for (x in Xval) {
    if (x <= 39) {
        print("Your grade is E(POOR)")
    } else if (x <= 49) {
        print("Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)")
    } else if (x <= 59) {
        print("Your grade is C(AVERAGE)")
    } else if (x <= 69) {
        print("Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)")
    } else {
        print("CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A")
    }
}
```

or you can use nested `ifelse` (which is vectorized `if...else...` statement)

```
x <- 0:100
ifelse(x <= 39,
    "Your grade is E(POOR)",
    ifelse(x <= 49,
        "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)",
        ifelse(x <= 59,
            "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)",
            ifelse(x <= 69,
                "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)",
                "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good example of using `cut()` with `labels`:

```
cut(x, breaks = c(0, 39, 49, 59, 69, 100), 
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    labels = c("Your grade is E(POOR)",
               "Your grade is D(BELOW AVERAGE)",
               "Your grade is C(AVERAGE)",
               "Your grade is B(ABOVE AVERAGE)",
               "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A")
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes a little beyond what was asked, but i feel this is good advice.
Whenever we are thinking of using nested `ifelse`s with a vector or list, It may be much simpler to use `dplyr::case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

grades <- case_when(
  x <= 39 ~ "Your grade is E (POOR)",
  x <= 49 ~ "Your grade is D (BELOW AVERAGE)",
  x <= 59 ~ "Your grade is C (AVERAGE)",
  x <= 69 ~ "Your grade is B (ABOVE AVERAGE)",
  TRUE     ~ "CONGRATULATIONS you scored an A"
)
```